# What is the maximum data rate of AS-Interface?

Tags: communication, can, data, serial-bus, automation

After online search, I could not find exact information except some marketing words. It is said that it supports up to 100m and can be extended up to 600m but there is no information of maximum data rate. I would be glad if someone can find something or tell from experience.

Comment: What is an "AS-Interface" and how does it's data rate relate to electrical engineering?

Comment: indeed, what is AS-interface? (I think how the data rate relates to electrical engineering is fairly apparent)

Comment: @Justme  it is Actuator-Sensor Interface and promoted as an alternative bus system with better performance than current industrial bus but there are not many info because of close community. I have already contacted with adaptors and promoters but no reply yet. So, needed some hints.

Comment: Many sources say it has a fixed bit rate of 167 kbps, or near it. Maybe the bit period is 6 microseconds, exactly, or near it. But the bit rate of the bus may not be what you are after, because there can be gaps between master commands and slave responses, so the data rate for a single device would be significantly slower. You might actually be more interested in some other parameter than maximum data rate.  @user253751 Maybe it relates or not, depending on context, which is why I asked. You assumed it is an electrical engineering question, even if you did not know what an AS-Interface is.